# Chapel equivalent to numpy `arange` / equivalent C for loop

Tags: chapel

What is the most idiomatic way in Chapel to loop over a series of real numbers with a fixed increment?

The C equivalent code would be:

```
for (x = 0.0; x<1.0; x+=0.1) {}
```

In Python/Numpy, one might write

```
x = numpy.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.1)
```

---

I could imagine writing an iterator as below, but is there an equivalent built into the language/standard modules? (and then of course, there is the question of writing parallel versions of this)

```
iter arange(start, stop, step) {
  var x = start;
  while (x < stop) {
     yield x;
     x += step;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know chapel, but it sounds like you just need to use the basic word "iterate" or "loop", you'll probably find similar. The guide has it, they look "raw" like what you ask: https://chapel-lang.org/docs/1.14/users-guide/base/forloops.html edit: I'm unsure if those range values can be fractions.. if not, you may be able to use division

Answer (score 4):

Just to expand on the iterator option : Defining an iterator then gets you nice array semantics with no extra work (thanks, Chapel!). Taking the code above and expanding it with some test cases:

```
// Define the general case
iter arange(type t, start, stop, step=1:t) {
  assert(stop > start, "Stop must be greater than start");
  assert(step > 0, "Step must be greater than 0");
  var x : t = start;
  while (x < stop) {
    yield x;
    x += step;
  }
}

// Overload for type from arguments
iter arange(start:?t, stop:t, step:t=1:t) {
  for x in arange(t, start, stop, step) do yield x;
}

// Overload for no start and default step = 1
iter arange(type t, stop) {
  for x in arange(t, 0, stop, 1) do yield x;
}

// Overload for no start and default step = 1
iter arange(stop:?t) {
  for x in arange(t, 0, stop, 1) do yield x;
}


// Example of simple iteration
for xi in arange(0.0,1.0,0.1) do writef(" %r",xi);
writef("\n");
for xi in arange(real,0,1,0.1) do writef(" %r",xi);
writef("\n");


// But Chapel allows other wonderful things once you
// define an iterator

// Array assignment
var x = arange(real, 0, 1, 0.1);
writeln(x);

// Promote a scalar function
var y = sin(2*pi*arange(real, 0, 1, 0.1));
for yi in y do writef(" %.3r",yi);
writef("\n");

// Step is optional
writeln(arange(real, 0, 10));
writeln(arange(0.0, 10.0));
```

Running this produces

```
 0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1
 0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1
0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0
 0 0.588 0.951 0.951 0.588 1.22e-16 -0.588 -0.951 -0.951 -0.588 -1.13e-15
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Chapel doesn't currently have built-in support for iterating over regular sequences of floating point values.  At times, we've discussed extending Chapel's range type to support floating point index types, but have not pursued that idea so far.  I believe that, at present, there isn't any standard library support for such patterns either.  Either of these would be reasonable feature requests to make on [Chapel's GitHub issues page](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues).

If I were writing this pattern today, I'd either write the iterator you did or simply put the while loop directly in my code.  For parallel iteration over a range of floating point values, creating a family of iterator overloads as described in Chapel's [parallel iterators primer](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/primers/parIters.html) would be the way to go.

Comment: thanks! follow up : if a parallel iterator doesn't exist, does Chapel just fall back to serial iteration in a forall loop?

Comment: Good question (and timing)!  This specific question has been under discussion recently.  Current thinking is that in a context where the `forall` keyword shows up syntactically in the source code, lack of a parallel iterator would result in a compiler error.  While in cases where the parallelism is implicit—like a promoted call, reduction, or reduce expression—the lack of a parallel iterator would result in falling back to a serial iterator.

Comment: I should add that when I say "recently" I mean that this discussion has been taking place since the 1.18.0 release, so what I described may not reflect what a user would see with a download today.  But the intention is for the next release to reflect these rules.